# Get a vertex in a vertex sequence

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

A vertex sequence by igraph seems not be a sequence. For example:

[image]

The v sequence by `V( module.net )` is a sequence, since I can access it by `[deg==1]`. But why it does't work when I try `peripheral[1]`? Any possible explanation for this?

The dataset for this example is not easy to be included, sorry for that.

//

I find the answer, the index of first vertex 'MED24' is 4, instead of 1. So if I want to get the first vertex, I have to do `peripheral[1]`. But this seems a little unreasonable. A replicatable example:

```
g = graph.ring(5)
V(g)$name = c('node1', 'node2', 'node3','node4','node5')
temp = V(g)[2:3]
```

If you want to access 'node3' from temp, you have to use `temp[3]` instead of `temp[2]`

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your error:

Comment: @RussHyde Can you share your test that worked? Did you perhaps include vertex one 1 in your sequence and then index by `[1]`?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I have seen the error of my ways.

Comment: See my supplements. But this is a little inconvenient

Comment: @RussHyde It's OK. I did the exact same thing too the first time. That's why it's always better when the OP actually supplies test data to make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always had trouble with vertex sequences and edge sequences. The problem with the indexing operator on those objects is that is searched by vector name, not position. So `peripheral[1]` is looking to see if vector 1 is in the list, it's not extracting the first element in the list.

The best i've come up with is converting the sequence to a simple vector and re-indexing the vector list. For example

```
el <- cbind(letters[1:5], letters[c(2,3,5,1,4)])
gg <- graph.edgelist(el)
p <- V(gg)[c(2,3)]
V(gg)[as.vector(p)[1]]
```

Actually, if you just want to extract the name of a particular vertex, then

```
p$name[1]
```

would work.

Comment: Yes your way works. See my supplements. But this is a little inconvenient

Comment: @yliueagle See my updated. If you just want the name of the vertex, then you can use `peripheral$name[1]`. That's probably more what you want. No need for `as.vector`.